# Is "Are you" correct when used in this sentence?

Tags: questions

I'm reading a book and found there is a sentence. Is it correct? I'm not an English native speaker and I just feel **Do you** is more proper here. Just want to confirm.

[image]

Comment: No, the book got it wrong. The sentence should say: ***Do** you want to cancel the update?*

Comment: Or, "Are you **sure that** you want . . . ?"

Comment: Or, "Are you **wanting** to cancel the updates," which is ugly but grammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am confirming that you're not wrong and your intuition is serving you well. **Do you want** is not a MORE proper but THE proper way to say that. *"Are you want"* makes *"want"* sound more like an adjective or a noun of some sort, but *"want"* being an adjective or a noun makes zero sense in that context.

Here's a little reminder for you: [the auxiliary verbs *do*, *does* and *did*](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/do-does-did/) (note that I said *"auxiliary"* as the usage of the verb *do* here is different from the way *do* is used normally when it's a regular verb) are always paired with verbs while different forms of the verb *to be* such as *"are"* and *"is"* are never paired with verbs. For more detailed information on this topic, follow the link in blue.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! BTW, are you Coach Shane? I watched many  Coach Shane's videos on Youtube.

Comment: I'm not him. I'm his close friend though. If you want to get access to his private lessons with a discount, I'm the guy to talk to.